# How to run a multivariate simulation a number of times and save each result in a specific variable?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a multivariate simulation 100 times and would like to save each run in a new variable and write it to a new csv file. I am not sure how to loop this through.

I am able to save each run by duplicating the code and naming the variables manually. This is tedious and I am sure there is a better way to achieve this.

```
library(dmutate)
mu <- c(4.23, 3.01, 2.91)
stddev <- c(1.23, 0.92, 1.32)

corMat <- matrix(c(1, 0.78, 0.23,
                   0.78, 1, 0.27,
                   0.23, 0.27, 1),
                 ncol = 3)

covMat <- stddev %*% t(stddev) * corMat

sims1 <- rmvnorm(10000, mu = mu, covMat)

sims2 <- rmvnorm(10000, mu = mu, covMat)

sims3 <- rmvnorm(10000, mu = mu, covMat)
.
.
.
sims100 <- rmvnorm(10000, mu = mu, covMat)

write.csv(sims1, file =  "Sims_out1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(sims2, file =  "Sims_out2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(sims3, file =  "Sims_out3.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I'd like to loop them and save them as different variables and write them into different csv files without having to copy them over a 100 times manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your example I would do this.

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  sims <- rmvnorm(10000, mu = mu, covMat)
  write.csv(sims1, file =  paste0("Sims_out",i,".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Basically you want to for loop a simulation and then write it in a new file.

Comment: And `lapply` version to save simulations in a list (better than separate objects): `sims_list <- lapply(1:100, function(i) { sims <- rmvnorm(10000, mu = mu, covMat); write.csv(sims1, file =  paste0("Sims_out",i,".csv"), row.names = FALSE); return(sims) })`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I could save each run into a different variable instead of writing it into a new .csv file?

Comment: You could use the `purrr` package from `tidyvers`. Then you can run this code `sim <- 100%>%purrr::rerun(rmvnorm(10000,mu = mu, covMat))` and have all simulations in a list. Then you could further use `purrr` to analyse your simulations but I would prefer if you would learn some more `purrr` before asking about more details. thx